# Install minimal Ubuntu when no internet access

Tags: networking, ubuntu, credentials

I have been trying to install 20.04.01 and have run into the brick wall of not being able to get on the network at the hotel here (separate question possed). Now I am thinking there should be an image that will at least write to the hard disk and let me boot from there. I have a mini.iso but it hits the same wall. I'll try an older version, 18.04 but I'll be flying blind

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems encountered on the way to getting this done. Since the laptop was built in 2007 it did not have wireless hardware. I should have checked. When I was able to get an Ethernet things got smoother. I still kept running into the 'operating system not found' problem and this was because in the BIOS (which I could not upgrade without windows) was very 'finicky' in that if you had a USB stick plugged in it showed up under 'disks'. If you didn't disable the hard drive AND (this is key) move the USB above the hard drive with the + option you'd get that error. When I figured all that out I could load images at will. Now I just need a wireless dongle and an SSD an this might be a good 50 pound paperweight that screems through the internet saying 'look at me witches'